# Proxy http and https requests with one virtualhost in Apache

Tags: apache-http-server

I have an Apache running on local IP 192.168.0.14. 
Internet requests to myweb.domain.sk are forwarded to 192.168.0.14:4444. Apache should only proxy the requests.

The web application runs on local network hostname **myweb** (MS IIS, different IP address)  and is accessible from the local network via both **http**://myweb.domain.sk and http**s**://myweb.domain.sk.

But, from internet I cannot access the web via HTTP, only HTTPS. This is the setting of the Apache:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.14:4444>
    ServerName myweb.domain.sk
    ServerAlias myweb.domain.sk
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
    ProxyVia Block
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyPassMatch ^/?(.*)  https://myweb.domain.sk/$1
    ProxyPassReverse / https://myweb.domain.sk/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/myweb.cer"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/myweb.key"
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

What else should I do to make the web accessible via http://myweb.domain.sk ?
Thank you

Comment: Where is Apache supposed to proxy those requests _to_? Back to itself, according to your configuration?

Comment: No, on local network it is a different IP, so the proxy works... If I used IP address instead of host name it would be a problem because the certificate only contains myweb domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP and HTTPS must use different ports. Because Apache's VirtualHost blocks include the port as part of their identification, you need *two* VirtualHost blocks for the same domain – one with `SSLEngine on`, the other without. (Each port needs corresponding `Listen` options and port-forward rules in your router, as well.)

```
# Port forwarding WAN:443 -> 192.168.0.14:4444
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.14:4444>
    ServerName myweb.domain.sk
    ServerAlias myweb.domain.sk
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
    ProxyVia Block
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyPassMatch ^/?(.*)  https://myweb.domain.sk/$1
    ProxyPassReverse / https://myweb.domain.sk/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/myweb.cer"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/myweb.key"
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>

# Port forwarding WAN:80 -> 192.168.0.14:8888
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.14:8888>
    ServerName myweb.domain.sk
    ServerAlias myweb.domain.sk
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
    ProxyVia Block
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyPassMatch ^/?(.*)  https://myweb.domain.sk/$1
    ProxyPassReverse / https://myweb.domain.sk/

    SSLProxyEngine on
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I do not understand, sorry. Apache listens on 80 and 443 as well as on 4444. But all requests from internet are forwarded to 4444. How should I specify the other vhirtualhost? Shall I change forwarding to only IP address and then create two virtual hosts one with *80 and a Rewrite rule to https:/myweb.domain.sk. But will proxy on the *443 host work if specified like in the above question?

Comment: I added an example.